# PassportJS not passing signup data to database, possible database connection issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using a scotch.io tutorial on setting up PassportJS local login for an app I'm working on. After setting up my signup/login pages, MongoDB, PassportJS, I tried making a test "account", and.... nothing happens. No redirect, no flash message, nothing. It seems like nothing is getting picked up to post to the database. I'm including the pertinent scripts below. I tried to be as faithful as possible to the tutorial layout (source: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local).

index.js (entry point for server)

```
// load dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// setup views
var ejs = require('ejs');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');

//database configuration
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// required for passport
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // for flash messages stored in-session

// routes
require('./routes')(app, passport);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

passport.js (passport settings)

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../user');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That e-mail address is already taken.'));
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User;
                    newUser.local.email = email;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }));

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'User not found.'));
            if(!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Invalid password, please try again.'));
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
};
```

/config/database.js

```
module.exports = {
    'url': 'mongodb://localhost:27017/users/'
}
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('pages/index');
    });

    app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        res.render('pages/login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
    });

    app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
        res.render('pages/signup', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user: req.user
        });
    });

    app.get('/addroom', function (req, res) {
        res.render('pages/addroom.ejs', {
            message: req.flash('addroomMessage')
        });
    });

    app.get('/propconfig', function (req, res) {
        res.render('pages/propconfig.ejs', {
            message: req.flash('propconfigMessage')
        });
    });
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};

// route middleware to ensure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

user.js (user schema)

```
// load dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// define user schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        email: String,
        password: String
    }
});

// METHODS
// generating a hash

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// creating model for user to expose to app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and finally, signup.ejs (template for signup UI)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node Authentication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script   src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Signup</h1>

    <!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
    <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>

    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <form action="/signup" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
            <div id="emailError"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
            <div id="passwordError"></div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
    </form>

    <hr>

    <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
    <p>Or go <a href="/">home</a>.</p>

</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/validate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** I commented out the email validation script I was using, and now the POST action is happening (why it wasn't before, I have no idea), but it's still not getting to the database.

**Update #2:** I tried running the server in debug mode. The console returned this information:

```
GET /signup 304 34.791 ms - -
  express:router dispatching POST /signup +28s
  express:router query  : /signup +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /signup +0ms
  express:router logger  : /signup +0ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /signup +1ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /signup +0ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /signup +3ms
  express:router session  : /signup +157ms
  express:router initialize  : /signup +2ms
  express:router authenticate  : /signup +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /signup +1ms
POST /signup - - ms - -
  express:router dispatching POST /signup +2m
  express:router query  : /signup +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /signup +0ms
  express:router logger  : /signup +1ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /signup +1ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /signup +2ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /signup +0ms
  express:router session  : /signup +4ms
  express:router initialize  : /signup +1ms
  express:router authenticate  : /signup +2ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /signup +1ms
POST /signup - - ms - -
```

Meanwhile, the browser stayed on `"Waiting for localhost..."` for about 2 or 3 minutes (without crashing or timing out), before finally returning "The localhost page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

**Update #3:** This is another debug log, checking all modules (not just Express):

```
  express:router dispatching POST /signup +39s
  express:router query  : /signup +4ms
  express:router expressInit  : /signup +1ms
  express:router logger  : /signup +2ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /signup +5ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /signup +3ms
  body-parser:json content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" +0ms
  body-parser:json skip parsing +4ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /signup +1ms
  body-parser:urlencoded content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" +0ms
  body-parser:urlencoded content-encoding "identity" +3ms
  body-parser:urlencoded read body +0ms
  body-parser:urlencoded parse body +60ms
  body-parser:urlencoded parse extended urlencoding +5ms
  express:router session  : /signup +8ms
  express-session fetching 6M-W_9dEFDmsPBvNp2d0UmeBE9gDuXMn +14ms
  express-session no session found +3ms
  express:router initialize  : /signup +9ms
  express:router authenticate  : /signup +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /signup +2ms
req.body: {"email":"matt@matt.matt","password":"pass1234"}
  mquery findOne +20ms users { 'local.email': 'matt@matt.matt' } { fields: {} }
  express-session saving EkaL4tXbUCZ9QXHDGt2XWxlgMjVGejAC +95ms
  express-session split response +1ms
  express-session set-cookie connect.sid=s%3AEkaL4tXbUCZ9QXHDGt2XWxlgMjVGejAC.cvTE1KsUvIzbnNqHP0ns9td75MUkR4mKRDvwuHk%2B4jE; Path=/; HttpOnly +4ms
  morgan log request +17ms
POST /signup 302 237.147 ms - 58
  express:router dispatching GET /signup +9ms
  express:router query  : /signup +2ms
  express:router expressInit  : /signup +0ms
  express:router logger  : /signup +1ms
  express:router cookieParser  : /signup +2ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /signup +0ms
  body-parser:json skip empty body +0ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /signup +13ms
  body-parser:urlencoded skip empty body +0ms
  express:router session  : /signup +1ms
  express-session fetching EkaL4tXbUCZ9QXHDGt2XWxlgMjVGejAC +1ms
  express-session session found +3ms
  express:router initialize  : /signup +1ms
  express:router authenticate  : /signup +1ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /signup +1ms
  express:view lookup "pages/signup.ejs" +6ms
  express:view stat "/media/matt/PORTABLE/myapp/views/pages/signup.ejs" +1ms
  express:view render "/media/matt/PORTABLE/myapp/views/pages/signup.ejs" +1ms
  express-session saving EkaL4tXbUCZ9QXHDGt2XWxlgMjVGejAC +18ms
  express-session split response +0ms
  morgan log request +10ms
GET /signup 200 50.407 ms - 1736
```

Comment: your `User.findOne` method does return anything?

Comment: @abdulbarik I'm not getting anything back. It seems like it's not connecting to the database at all, in mongo it says the database is empty

Comment: maybe add a console.log(err) in your callback function for User.findOne in that if(err). also, placing few logs here and there would be of help too, you would at least know where does the control going.

Comment: @PrzemekLewandowski thanks for the tip, I've added a couple of logs and it's not returning any info. I also added some debug info to the original post. For some reason a connection isn't being made.

Comment: you've tried to use wireshark or fiddler to examine what is being sent?

Comment: make sure you can ping all the endpoints from a terminal, might also be a firewall issue

Comment: you are listening on port 3000, but are you sure you are issuing a request to this port?

Comment: ping your 3000 server and see if it is even running

Comment: I'm trying Wireshark now, in the meantime I pinged the server and it's up, I don't think you can ping a port though

Comment: yes you can ping a port http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

Comment: okay I followed the instructions there. According to nmap both ports are open (3000 for Node server and 27017 for MongoDB)

Comment: what is your mongoose version ?

Comment: @manishg 4.8.7 (latest version as of 12 Mar 2017)

Comment: I think `newUser.save` doesn't return at all,  `done()` is never called and it hangs. Can you put a log before `return done(null, newUser);` to assert this theory? If this is indeed what's happening then it is linked to this issue https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4064

Comment: @manishg I'm putting console.logs everywhere I can think of, and nothing is coming back. I also tried switching to `.$__save` instead of `.save` which seems to be the gist of that github thread, and there is no change.

Comment: Looks like you only have logs from `express` module. Can you use `set DEBUG = *` (windows) and restart your server ?  and see if you have more logging from other modules.

Comment: So is newUser.save called or even that's not called?

Comment: Looks like the database call is being made `mquery findOne +20ms users { 'local.email': 'matt@matt.matt' } { fields: {} }`  Can you check to see if you have a entry in the database ? It should be in `users` table inside `users` database.

Comment: @manishg I guess it's not being called, it's not returning anything in the console.

Comment: @Veeram the database `users` is empty.

Comment: Just to confirm. How are you checking the database ? Are you saying `users` db is there but no `users` table ?. I just want to list steps because it can be confusing at times. On Mongo shell you use `show dbs` to list the databases and `use users` to switch to `users` db and `db.users.find()` to view table data.

Comment: How difficult is for you to share your project? May be on GitHub ?

Comment: @Veeram when I run mongo shell, I enter `show dbs` and it lists `users (empty)`. And just to double-check, when I enter `use users` and then `db.users.find()` it returns nothing.

Comment: @manishg that's a good idea, I'll try and get this up on github and then get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. What version of mongodb shell and server are you  on ?

Comment: @Veeram I'm using MongoDB v 2.2.24 and Express 4.14.1

Comment: Sorry not the node js mongo db driver. I meant the mongo db server. Can you run `db.version()` on mongo shell ?

Comment: ah ok sorry. The db version is 2.6.10

Comment: @Matt: did you get a chance to host the code on github?

Comment: @Matt  did you check  log messages on mongo console   ?

Comment: @manishg sorry for the delay, [here](https://github.com/maetyu26/passportproject) it is.

Comment: @Veeram the global log doesn't seem to have anything useful, just connections but no indication of data sent

Comment: @Matt The code in github is not working. You may want to update the routes.js to remove the passport code as the server is crashing just as you mentioned in one of your comment in the answer and also remove the console logs from passport local sign up function. However I made it work by doing the above mentioned update and I get the profile page with `Local

id: 58cb30e0a7647520d497a092
email: matt@matt.matt
password: $2a$08$guUWS2YHPdEb57DyADUOjelOV/G5vPzB6kcRBfbS8um1r6nNO8Nbi` response. So I still need to figure out why it is not working for you.

Comment: @Veeram ok this is really strange. The result you are getting is exactly as intended in the tutorial. I've reset my `routes.js` back to what it was that I originally posted:  `app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
 }));`
and I'm back to square one...

Comment: @Matt Yeah I have followed your original post and it has been working for me all this time. Other thing I just notice your `package.json` doesn't have all dependency listed. Looks like the part of it is missing.

Comment: @Matt Can you run the mongo db profiling and see the queries it is logging ? Go to mongo console - run `use users` - `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` and run your application - back to mongo console - `db.getCollectionNames()` to view collections and the n`db.system.profile.find().pretty()` and look at the last couple of queries and see if you are able to see the read n insert query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your code. I think it helped me fix this faster. I was able to reproduce your issue. Here is a diff of what I did to fix your issue

### Change #1

In routes.js, I modified passport to use `local-signup` defined in passport.js instead of your existing function:

```
diff --git a/routes.js b/routes.js
index a6166b7..e2a742f 100644
--- a/routes.js
+++ b/routes.js
@@ -13,30 +13,12 @@ module.exports = function(app, passport) {
                res.render('pages/signup', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
        });

-       app.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
-    passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login'},
-        function (req, email, password, done) {
-            process.nextTick(function () {
-                User.findOne({'local.email': email}, function (err, user) {
-                    if (err)
-                        return done(err);
-                    if (user) {
-                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That e-mail address is already taken.'));
-                    } else {
-                        var newUser = new User;
-                        newUser.local.email = email;
-                        newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
-                        newUser.save(function (err) {
-                            if (err){
-                                throw err;}
-                            //res.redirect("/path")        
-                            return done(null, newUser);
-                        });
-                    }
-                });
-            });
-        });
-});
+           // process the signup form
+    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
+        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
+        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
+        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
+    }));

        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
                successRedirect: '/profile',
```

### Change #2

Commented out few comments and made sure `if err` is closed

```
diff --git a/config/passport.js b/config/passport.js
index dde7628..398796e 100644
--- a/config/passport.js
+++ b/config/passport.js
@@ -23,7 +23,6 @@ module.exports = function(passport) {
                process.nextTick(function() {
                        User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
                                if (err)
-                                       console.log(err);
                                        return done(err);
                                if (user) {
                                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That e-mail address is already taken.'));
@@ -31,9 +30,9 @@ module.exports = function(passport) {
                                        var newUser = new User;
                                        newUser.local.email = email;
                                        newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
-                                       newUser.$__save(function(err) {
+
+                                       newUser.save(function(err) {
                                                if (err)
-                                                       console.log(err);
                                                        throw err;
                                                console.log(User);
                                                console.log(newUser);
```

Here is a gif to show it is successful:
[image]

I have submitted a [pull](https://github.com/maetyu26/passportproject/pull/1) request to your branch.

Comment: I just gitcloned your edits to my computer and.... it WORKED!!! **Thank you!!!** I'm gonna sit and read the changes carefully to make sure I understand what's going on, but it looks like we're in business!!

Comment: let me know if this did indeed work and ill be happy to award

Answer (score 3):

First change you local strategy like this

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function () {
        //LocalStrategy verify callback
    }
));
```

Then change you route /signup like this

```
app.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login'},
        function (req, email, password, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {
                User.findOne({'local.email': email}, function (err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    if (user) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That e-mail address is already taken.'));
                    } else {
                        var newUser = new User;
                        newUser.local.email = email;
                        newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                        newUser.save(function (err) {
                            if (err){
                                throw err;}
                            //res.redirect("/path")        
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        })(req, res, next);
});
```

you can redirect to other pages from res.redirect("/path") like this

That route you defined in your routes i.e

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

it was not working because you can not define passport.authenticate directly in your routes, and you database connection is working fine it is fetching results from database no problem with database connection.

Comment: I tried the code you provided, and the server crashed. I removed the `(req, res, next)` at the end, and that brought me back to the same result from my 2nd update. (empty response/no data sent)

Comment: have you imported User in routes?
i.e var User = require('./user');

Comment: same result there.